# android application launching another application and waiting for feedback

Tags: android

I want to load to my application some images choosed by user.
Is there any way to launch his default file explorer and get images choosed in this application?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setDataAndType(path, "application/filetype"); 
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);


try {
    startActivity(intent);
} 
catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
    Toast.makeText(OpenPdf.this, 
        "No app available", 
        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```